# Convert SQLLite Date Integer to Java Date

Tags: java, sqlite

I am working with SQLLite code that stores a date as an integer (I am assuming in the so many days since style). I would like to convert this int to a date but this...

```
public int getDate(){
...
Date d = new Date(m.getDate());
```

Seems to give me the wrong value.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Problem 1.)

If anyone has the same issue, the problem is a SQLLite Integer isn't exactly an Integer. If I call...

```
item.setDate(rs.getInt("date"));
```

I get a negative number, apparently this is because the value in the DB is greater than the max value for a java int. Once I change to...

```
item.setDate(rs.getLong("date"));
```

The value is as expected. This is despite the table values created as an INTEGER.

Now I get the the value "1383769720540277" which matches the DB, however,...

```
Date d = new Date(m.getDate()*1000L);
```

Gives me a date of 886-10-29 which also doesn't look right

**Update 2**

According to [this](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm) tool it must be in milliseconds * 1000. I am working on a way to handle this since .001 is a double and can't be used to create a long without rounding.

Comment: Can you post a sample SQLLite integer value and the date you expect?  java.util.Date expects milliseconds since 1/1/70, not days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQLLite integer can be up to 8 bytes (-2^63 to 2^63-1); see http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.

A Java integer is only 4 bytes (-2^31 to 2^31-1); a long is 8 bytes; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

It's now 1,384,621,644 seconds since the UNIX epoch; that's 1,384,621,644,000 milliseconds or 1,384,621,644,000,000 microseconds.  You definitely need a Java long to hold these since they're greater than 4 bytes (4,294,967,295)

It looks like your timestamp is in microseconds.  The `java.util.Date` constructor takes milliseconds since the epoch.  You can calculate mililseconds from microseconds by dividing by 1000; no need to convert to a string and back:

`item.setDate(rs.getLong("date")/1000);`

Comment: Great comment thanks except the last line. Have you tried that? Because when I did I got a compile time exception saying it could not cast a double to a long. granted I used 1000L instead of 1000.

Comment: Also I glanced over the SQLLite page you posted before but I don't see where it lists the sizes for the datatypes

Comment: Yes, this worked for me: `long ts = 1384621644000000L; Date dt = new Date(ts/1000);`  The integer size info is under the Storage Classes and Datatypes section: INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple problems here...

1. The Integer type in SQLLite is apparently longer than the Integer type in Java. This means just because it says Integer doesn't mean you should use an integer. In my case I needed to use a long to get the proper value.

   rs.getLong("date");
2. The application that was adding the Date as an integer was storing it with too much detail. In order to make it work I had to lob off the last 3 chars.

   String s = String.valueOf(rs.getLong("date"));

   s = s.substring(0, s.length()-3);

   item.setDate(Long.parseLong(s));

Once both of these were completed it seemed to process correctly. If someone has more detail/better links on what is happening feel free to elaborate for the check.